# Is the requirement to access all functionality over a website functional or non functional?

Tags: requirements

The title pretty much sums up my question.
Is the requirement for a website functional or non functional?

For me the *what* needs to be implemented is a functional requirement.
The non functional requirements describe the way *how* to implements this functionality.

That's why I tend to mark it as a non functional requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requesting a specific access channel is a functional requirement.

An example for a nonfunctional requirement would be that requests to that website must be responded within 2 seconds (under certain conditions that would be further defined of course).